# From time to time traefik stops to work

Tags: docker, traefik

We use `"traefik:v1.6.4-alpine"` docker-image. Container is running with the following args:

```
--debug --web --web.statistics --web.metrics --web.metrics.prometheus --rancher.
```

From time to time traefik stops to work. The web interface works fine, but resources are not available. Only restarting the container resolves the issue.  How can I debug the issue or collect required data to solve the issue?